# PPPoE-содениние, коммутатор и два роутера?

Tags: сеть, wifi, ethernet

Есть `ethenrnet`-кабель входщий в квартиру. Интернет предоставляется с помощью PPPoE-соиденения (логин/пароль)

Я хочу, чтобы у меня в квартире работало сразу два роутера, которые бы раздавали `Wi-Fi` -- один на кухне, второй в дальней комнате (спальня)

На ум приходит приобритение коммутатора, в который будет подключен интернет-кабель и от комматутора будут идти еще два кабеля на мои роутеры. Подскажите, реализуемо ли это? Нужно ли как-то настраивать свитч?

Comment: Ну да, либо через Switch подключать по проводам, либо использовать второй роутер как ретранслятор. Многие роутеры поддерживают этот режим. Т.е. будет по wi-fi получать интернет и по нему же раздавать.

Comment: Ретранслятор режет скорость существенно. а как вообще коммутатор настраивается? Там такой жн интерфейс как у роутера (192.168.0.*)?

Comment: Да режет, конечно же. Примерно такие же интерфейсы как в роутере, да. Только настроек про балансировку больше.

Comment: Это мне для настройки нужен комп с ethernet кабелем?

Comment: Да⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Answer (score 0):

Купил еще один маршрутизатор, на нем настроил PPPoE соединение, а второй роутер подключил уже к нему в LAN разъем, и на втором роутере включил службу DHCP.

Теперь в квартире две изолированные точки доступа. Задал им разные каналы, чтоб наверняка

Answer (score 0):

Первый роутер включаешь в интернет. Во втором отключаешь dhcp-сервер и вставляешь LAN-LAN. Тогда сети станут не изолированными друг от друга.

Comment: А при выключенном DHCP на втором роутере нет подключения к интернету